# Why is concatenating strings with .join quicker than with the + operation in Python

Tags: python, string

So I recently read an article online about optimizing Python, and it said that concatenating strings with `.join()`

```
concatenatedString = " ".join (["Hello", "world!"])
```

is quicker than with the + operator

```
concatenatedString = "Hello " + "world!"
```

I tried both of them on a python debugger, and I found that using `.join()` is indeed quicker than using the + operator.

Why is this?

Comment: It helps, but the answer is slightly different, as it is with the += operator

Comment: Added some additional prior instances of this question to the duplicate list. BTW, note that this is very old advice, and concatenating strings with `+` is not nearly as slow with Python-of-today as it was 15 years ago. Not that `join()` isn't faster, but it's not _as much_ faster as it used to be. Keep an eye on the vintage of what you read on the topic.

Comment: (Mind, "why" questions are somewhat questionable to the extent that they go beyond asking what _is best_, into asking _why_ that thing is best; our scope is narrowly focused on "_practical_, answerable questions"; if you already know that X is the right way to do something, and knowing _why_ it's the best way won't change how you write code, it doesn't change how you go about the practice of software development, and is therefore not a practical question).